# Getdate() equivalent for Jet / Access database. Need last month records

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I was reading other questions posted and found many examples to retrieve last month records. I am using Visual Studio 2008 query builder to retrieve records from an Access mdb and when I enter the following query it is displaying me an error that getdate is not a valid function:

```
where [Transaction Date]     
   between dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, dateadd(MM, -1, getdate())), 0)
       and dateadd(ms, -3, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, dateadd(MM, -1, getdate())) + 1, 0))
```

What is the correct sql query to extract last month records from an mdb?

This is a query I have, but it is giving me records from this month also amd just need last month:

```
  SELECT
   [Product Code], [Description One], [Transaction Number], Quantity, [Sales Value], Cost, [Transaction Date], [Transaction Time], Department, [Type Code], Cashier, [Computer Name], [Customer Code]
  FROM
   [Product History] 
  WHERE
   ([Transaction Date] >= DATEADD('m', - 2, NOW()))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
    DATEDIFF('m', [Transaction Date], DATE()) = 1
```

Comment: That would work however I’m think I’m right in saying that if you had an index on the Transaction Date column it would not be used in this query which might result in less than optimal query performance. I am however open to correction on this but it is certainly my experience

Answer (score 3):

The Getdate() equivalent in access is Now().

Comment: Now returns date & time, Date returns date only, I think Date is more suitable for this query.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make a custom function in access to work out the start and end of next month and other common dates. Here is a sample of the function with the start of next month and end of next month defined

```
Public Function Common_dates_SQL(strCommon_date As String) As Date
On Error GoTo Error_trap:

Select Case strCommon_date

    Case "Start_Last_Month"
        Common_dates_SQL = Date - ((DateDiff("d", DateValue("01/" & DatePart("m", Date) & "/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)), Date)) + 1)

    Case "End_Last_Month"
    Common_dates_SQL = (Date - ((DateDiff("d", DateValue("01/" & DatePart("m", Date) & "/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)), Date)) + 1)) - (DatePart("d", Date - ((DateDiff("d", DateValue("01/" & DatePart("m", Date) & "/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)), Date)) + 1)) - 1)

End Select
DoCmd.Hourglass False
Exit Function

Error_trap:
DoCmd.Hourglass False
MsgBox "An error happened in sub Common_dates, error description " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "FRapps"

End Function
```

The full function goes on for a lot longer and include quarters/years and other things that I get asked for

You can then use this function in your SQL query like this

```
SELECT tblFoo.*
FROM tblFoo
WHERE (((Created_date) Between Common_dates_SQL('Start_last_month') And Common_dates_SQL('END_last_month')));
```

Comment: UDFs can really slow queries down and should not be necessary for dates.

Comment: I should have added that most of the time I use these functions are in dynamically generated SQL queries so the SQL that is passed is just that date as opposed to the UDF. However I do very rarely use them straight in SQL queries but I can't comment on the performance as the only time I have used them is for small queries

Answer (score 1):

The zeroth day of the month is the last day of the previous month, this works in both Jet SQL and VBA.

End of last month:

```
 DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
```

Start of last month:

```
 DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1)
```